# Why my layout look like this ? Here is my XML file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Here Is my

[image: Device picture]

and XML code first i use a Linear Layout then card View and other views so why my view overwrite where is the problem please watch the AVD picture and tell me where is the error.Sorry for bad english.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/item_linerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/item_id"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/item_id" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_AuthorName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Author"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/item_title"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_pages"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
                android:text="100"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is overlapping?

Comment: Sir the last textView id-="@+id/item_pages" is overlapping.

Comment: You have constrained the last textview to the parent. Change the constraint to app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_AuthorName" .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your root layout(In your case LinearLayout). I recommend you to read this [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec) to understand system overlapping. I hope it helps)

Comment: I thought you wanted to disable status bar overlapping, for textView (item_pages) , Just use app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent". app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

Answer (score 0):

I have removed redundant `LinearLayout` parent and made `CardView` parent. Also your `TextView` with id item_pages is not overlapping.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Title"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/item_AuthorName"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/item_id" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_AuthorName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:text="Author"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/item_id"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/item_title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_pages"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
            android:text="100"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```